# Python: 2 level sibling import

Tags: python, import, project-structure

given the following file structure (example)

```
library_project\
 |- __init__.py
 |
 |--- utils_a\
 |     |- __init__.py
 |     |- util_functions_a.py
 |
 |--- utils_b\
 |     |- __init__.py
 |     |
 |     |--- utils_b_1\
 |     |     |- __init__.py
 |     |     |- util_function_b1.py
 |     |
 |     |--- utils_b_2\
 |     |     |- __init__.py
 |     |     |- util_function_b2.py
```

and a second project

```
other_project\
 |- __init__.py
 |- run.py
```

in run.py

```
from library_project.utils_b.util_function_b2 import do_something
do_something()
```

How can `util_function_b2.py` use functions from `util_functions_a.py`?

All examples for relative imports that I found assume that the imported package is a sibling package (e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) and not 2 levels up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`import` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) allows you to use an arbitrary number of `.` dots to refer to packages further up the tree.

- `.` refers to the same package; `utils_b_2`.
- `..` refers to the same shared parent package, `utils_b`
- `...` refers to `library_project`

From `util_function_b2` you can refer to `util_functions_a` with 3 dots:

```
from ...utils_a.util_functions_a import somename
```

Comment: thanks, I recreated my example above and it works exactly like you said

Answer (score -1):

Given the Directory structure, to import "util_function_b2.py"

```
from library_project.urils_b.utils_b_2.until_function_b2 import *
```

How can util_function_b2.py use functions from util_functions_a.py -

You can either add the project to python path.

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/library_project/')
```

then,

```
from  from library_project.utils_a imoprt *
```

or there is a way to do with relative addressing using "."

Comment: Don't add the `library_project` folder to `sys.path`, you add the *parent* to `sys.path`. That's not the issue here however, the question is about how to use `..` relative module names in the `import` statement.